# Facebook send message

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I am new to node.js and want to send private message to my facebook friends. I used [facebook-chat](https://github.com/SideraX/node-facebook-chat)

but above framework is not supported.
Please give me sample code or example for the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "not supported"? Are you getting an error? We need more info before we can help

Comment: I am sorry that frameworks has mentioned "No longer supported" on their github page. I have checked that framework and it works fine. But in future they might stop supporting.

Answer (score 0):

I use facebook-chat-api module:

```
var login = require("facebook-chat-api");

login({
  email: "your@mail.com",
  password: "password"
}, function callback(err, api) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  var userId = "12345";
  var msg = {
    body: "Hey! That's Node.js!"
  };
  api.sendMessage(msg, userID);
});
```

Example above didn't work with (string) user nicknames - only with user ids.